# Change COM Version Number

Tags: com, visual-foxpro

How can I change the version number on a Visual FoxPro COM dll?

[image: com version number screenshot]

---

I've changed the version number here but apparently that only controls the file version number, not the [COM Version Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/version).

[image: vfp version screenshot]

---

I'm guessing this is not possible within VFP but maybe there's a way outside of VFP?

Comment: You are absolutely correct in that changing the info in the project information doesn't really change anything. Question, have you imported the new dll into the project? If you have then there shouldn't be much of an issue...Personally I no longer work that much with Fox, but I do seem to remember that the project info didn't really do anything.

Comment: Hi @Hank - it's nice to see the correct version number in VS so that I know I'm using the right version 